# Is ねえ negative in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, negation

> オカダ１勝目バクステ「余裕の勝利。人間ってのは**ねぇ**、余裕の時はこうやって、壁に手をついて立つんだよ

The translation for this sentence is:

> After finally winning his first match オカダ (leaning his hand against the wall) says:"A man stands like this, with his hands on a wall, when things are easy in his life"

If there was no ねぇ in that sentence it would make perfect sense for the translation.

Comment: I think l'électeur answered your question perfectly. Just wanted to add that there is no indication in オカダ１勝目 that Okada "finally" won his first match. It's just that he won his first match, which he thinks was an easy win and thus the 余裕 pose he is making. It could be just the first match in the tournament.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「人間ってのは**ねぇ**、余裕の時はこうやって、壁に手をついて立つんだよ 」

The 「ねぇ」 here is only a variant of 「ね」, the filler particle.  It has no particular meaning of its own and it is neither affirmative or negative in nature.

Here, 「ねぇ」 has nothing to do with the informal, "Kanto-tough-guy" 「ない」.

The sentence still stands if the 「ねぇ」 is dropped or replaced by another filler like 「な」 or 「なぁ」.